# Error:(48, 13) error: illegal start of expression

Tags: android

> I get this error occcure when I build sign apk don't know but when I build simple apk these error does not occur,plz help me resolve this.

```
    PTAdChartboostBridge.s_activity.get)
    {

    PTAdChartboostBridge(new Runnable);

        {

            public void run();
            {
                if (PTAdChartboostBridge.appId() == null || PTAdChartboostBridge.appSignature() == null) {

                    Chartboost.startWithAppId(PTAdChartboostBridge.activity, PTAdChartboostBridge.appId(), PTAdChartboostBridge.appSignature());
                    Chartboost.setLoggingLevel(Level.ALL);
                    Chartboost.setDelegate(delegate);
                    Chartboost.onCreate(PTAdChartboostBridge.activity);

                    initComplete = true;

                    Chartboost.onStart(PTAdChartboostBridge.activity);
                    return;
                }

            }

        }

error is in this code plzz help???
```

Comment: So in line 48 is an error, but where does that line number refers to in your snippet?

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing whatever you are trying to. Your format is totally wrong. 
I would suggest you go through basics again.

However correct format will be as below

```
new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
         if (PTAdChartboostBridge.appId() == null || PTAdChartboostBridge.appSignature() == null) {

            Chartboost.startWithAppId(PTAdChartboostBridge.activity, PTAdChartboostBridge.appId(), PTAdChartboostBridge.appSignature());
            Chartboost.setLoggingLevel(Level.ALL);
            Chartboost.setDelegate(delegate);
            Chartboost.onCreate(PTAdChartboostBridge.activity);

            initComplete = true;

            Chartboost.onStart(PTAdChartboostBridge.activity);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i m new in android i dnt knw much can u correct my further mistake